# Resolving ambiguous abbreviations in forvalues

Tags: for-loop, stata, ambiguous, abbreviation

My variables are named as follows:

```
F_1idoXyea_2_1988
F_1idoXyea_2_1989
F_1idoXyea_2_1990
```

Given the code

```
forvalues i = 2(1)12 {
    qui replace F_1idoXyea_`i' = F_1idoXyea_`i'*exp(_b[F_1idoXyea_`i'])
}
```

an error message appears

```
F_1idoXyea_2 ambiguous abbreviation
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

The use of a `forvalues` loop is not the cause of this problem. It's pure and simple: given that you have

```
F_1idoXyea_2_1988
F_1idoXyea_2_1989
F_1idoXyea_2_1990
```

**any reference whatsoever** to  `F_1idoXyea_2` is ambiguous. Stata allows abbreviations of variable names (unless that's disabled) but the only way to clear this up is to tell Stata which variable you mean.

It's on all fours with this homely situation. You have three friends Peter A, Peter B and Peter C and you start telling a story about Peter to someone who knows them all. Which Peter are you talking about? is then a fair question.

Comment: The point is that I creating variables with comand `xi, pre(F_1) i.ido*i.year` then the variable name is created by Stata.

Comment: No doubt, but how does that change the question? If you want to loop over them all, then a wildcard such as `F_1idoXyea_2_????` or `F_1idoXyea_2*` should be considered.